# java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/jdk5/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: linux, apache

when I am trying deployed application on beta server (It is based on linux).
I have found below error in `apache-tomcat` log file(`localhost.log`).

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: /usr/local/jdk5/jre/lib/i386/xawt/libmawt.so: libXext.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1647)
at java.lang.Runtime.load0(Runtime.java:769)
at java.lang.System.load(System.java:967)
at java.lang.ClassLoader$NativeLibrary.load(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary0(ClassLoader.java:1751)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadLibrary(ClassLoader.java:1668)
at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary0(Runtime.java:822)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:992)
at sun.security.action.LoadLibraryAction.run(LoadLibraryAction.java:50)
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at java.awt.Toolkit.loadLibraries(Toolkit.java:1509)
at java.awt.Toolkit.<clinit>(Toolkit.java:1530)
at java.awt.Color.<clinit>(Color.java:250)
----
```

please help me.Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have faced similar error and below is the solution that work for me.
Please set Java path for your tomcat server in file `catalina.sh`.
Set `JAVA_HOME` path to your jdk version which is same as your compile version.

For Example :

```
JAVA_HOME=/usr/java5/jdk1.5.0_21
```

If required please also set `CATALINA_HOME` to your tomcat installation directory.

May this will help you.

Answer (score 1):

The most probable thing is that you have included the awt libraries (or the complete java runtime) in your served `.jar` deployed file.  Don't do that, as it will make your code to run only on environments like the development system you have used to test the application.  Probably you are trying to deploy your application to Windows and linux platforms and it's asking for `Xt.so` linux libraries (to use awt over X11, on windows it uses a different library).  Check your packaging configuration (the modules included in the `.jar` file) and don't include platform libraries (like the java runtime) that are architecture dependant.  A common error is to *include everything* and you get this problem.  Think twice before including some package in your deployment.

Comment: I suppose you cannot tick my answer as *the answer* but if you're glad, you can upvote it :)

Comment: Hi Luis , Actually I have not 15 reputation on stackoverflow yet so It can not allow me.so once i got it I will definitely upvote your answer.Thanks.

Comment: oops... sorry then, you are equally wellcome to SO. :) >You'll get soon, but no need to do it.  I've enough with your grateful comment.